# Conditional population of Java Array constant

Tags: java, arrays

I want to populate a CharSequence with one of two array constants, depending on a condition. I then want to pass it as an argument to an AlertDialog. The code below is what I'm trying to achieve, but line 7 gives a compile-time error "items cannot be resolved to a variable".

```
if (presetItemId == 0) {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Delete", "Edit" };
} else{
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Delete"};
}
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Meal Item")
        .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 1) {
```

Coding it a different way (as below) gives "Array constants can only be used in initializers" for lines 3 and 5:

```
final CharSequence[] items;
if (presetItemId == 0) {
    items = { "Delete", "Edit" };
} else{
    items = { "Delete"};
}
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Meal Item")
        .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 1) {
                    editRecord(Integer.parseInt(id));
                }
                else if (item == 0) {
```

Any ideas for how I can achieve what I want to do here?

Comment: which one is line 7 of your code & what is item(int) type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java allows you to declare a `final` variable, and assign it later, as long as it's not used before then.  Try including your array initializer (`{ "Delete", "Edit" }`) in an array creation expression (`new CharSequence[] { "Delete", "Edit" }`):

```
final CharSequence[] items;
if (presetItemId == 0) {
    items = new CharSequence[] { "Delete", "Edit" };
} else{
    items = new CharSequence[] { "Delete"};
}
new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle("Meal Item")
    .setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { //...
```